express vpn still trying to connect after uninstall
I'm using ubunu 20.04 and I have very similar problem to this question.
I have just discovered on my logs that express.vpn is still trying to connect every minute despite being removed using:
sudo dpkg -r expressvpn

the logs say:
expressvpn.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
expressvpn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/expressvpnd: No such file or directory

I have found packages left in systemd but also in .config
I'm not very confident using command lines especially rm and wanted to check that these are correct to try as there was no feedback from the user:
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/expressvpn.service
sudo reboot

Would:
sudo apt purge expressvpn 

be good to use or would it not remove dependencies?
Could there be any problems following removing them and is there anything else I should check to make sure they are all removed?

So to find out what's installed, run the following command:
dpkg -l | grep -i expressvpn

This should show all relevant packages that contain the search term "expressvpn" in the name or the description.
Yes, you can use purge to get rid of this:
sudo apt purge expressvpn

And also run this command for any other related packages that were listed in the output of the first command: dpkg -l | grep -i expressvpn.

Next, search for systemd services that may be running:
sudo systemctl status -a | grep -i expressvpn

this may return some false positives that are echoed back from that command. You should look for anything listed as a service like expressvpn.service for example.
The following examples will use the generic name "expressvpn.service" but this will work for any related service name as well:
To stop a service:
sudo systemctl stop expressvpn

To disable a service:
sudo systemctl disable expressvpn

To completely block a service:
sudo systemctl mask expressvpn

Do this for any services listed in the previous systemctl status command.

Other than that, we would need to see the exact logs you're referring to. You can edit your question and then copy and paste the logs into your question and then use CTRL+K to format it as code before posting please. And please be specific to tell us what you found in systemd etc.

EDIT 1:
First, go into your NetworkManager or network settings and look for the expressVPN if you set it up through NetworkManager.
Then, select the VPN profile (if shown) and delete the VPN profile.
Next, it looks like the errors in your logs are because the files were deleted before removing or purging the expressvpn package. So first, reinstall the expressvpn package.
Create a working directory and then change directory to this:
cd
mkdir express
cd express

Download the expressvpn package:
wget 'https://www.expressvpn.works/clients/linux/expressvpn_3.79.0.0-1_amd64.deb'

Install the package:
sudo apt install ./expressvpn_3.79.0.0-1_amd64.deb

Delete the working directory to clean up:
cd
rm -r ~/express

Reboot for good measure.
Finally, purge expressvpn:
sudo apt purge expressvpn

Again, reboot for good measure and then check for any errors.

At this point, the problem should be solved. Purging with apt purge, rather than simply removing with apt remove should purge the system of any configuration files when removing the package.
In the future, if you need to remove a package and you want to completely remove the package, you should use sudo apt purge or even sudo apt remove instead of dpkg -r regardless of how the package was installed (so long as it was a deb package). There are certain hooks and scripts that apt can automatically run to clean up the system to prevent issues, on top of the fact that purging should remove all the related config and systemd files.
If you still get the errors at this point, then delete those files and reboot:
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/expressvpn.service
sudo reboot

As for your question about the config files in your home directory: yes, you should delete the config files in your home directory as apt will not automatically delete files in your user's home directory.
Please let me know if the problem persists and then you could try to install again and then mask the service before purging.

thank you for that, and how to format, its not working in the comments   the output for sudo systemctl status -a | grep -i expressvpn showed the same as the log, trying to connect every second and also that the expressvpn Daemon starting and stopping frequently too.

the system files are in: /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service, and  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/expressvpn.service  but the commands sudo systemctl stop expressvpn  or disable doesnt seem to do anything

do I need to run   sudo systemctl stop expressvpn.service to remove them from the systemd files as they are still there after running the commands as just expressvpn

would manually deleting the .config file of expressvpn from homefolder work for deleting it?

@papercup I added some additional instructions based on your logs. So reinstall the package because your errors show it's looking for files that no longer exist, and then use apt purge to properly remove the package, along with all the configuration files. Using apt remove instead of purge will not remove configuration files so I think purging the package will solve the issue. To answer your question, about dependencies when using apt purge, apt will always ask for confirmation and at this point, it will list what packages will be removed. If you see packages you want to keep then select N

@papercup If you do want to remove dependencies that were installed when you installed expressvpn, you can run sudo apt autoremove to remove any unneeded dependencies. Although, review the list of packages that will be removed before selecting Y because you might want to keep some of these packages. For example, if you want to keep openvpn and you see this listed for removal, then select N to abort autoremove, and then explicitly install the package(s) you want to keep: sudo apt install openvpn and then run sudo apt autoremove This time, openvpn should not be listed for removal.

@papercup I felt that this was a bit out of scope for the answer to your original question but tf you have any further questions about apt or purging / removal, please feel free to ask a separate question and someone can answer that.

thank you, i think this sorted it out:  sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/expressvpn.service
sudo reboot

@papercup Awesome. Don't forget to click the checkmark icon to the left to mark this as the accepted solution if this fixed your issue. Thanks.
